# Query for JPA endpoint needs explicit type casts

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jpa, enums

I'm currently doing an endpoint to find a list of `exchange_request` by its `status`. For it, I defined this query in my repository:

```
@Query("SELECT er FROM ExchangeRequest er WHERE er.status = :status")
    fun findByStatus(status: ExchangeRequestStatus): Optional<List<ExchangeRequest>>
```

And I defined this in my migration:

```
CREATE TYPE EXCHANGE_REQUEST_STATUS AS ENUM ('PENDING', 'ACCEPTED', 'REJECTED', 'CANCELLED');
CREATE CAST (VARCHAR AS EXCHANGE_REQUEST_STATUS) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;
```

I've been looking up on the internet for already some hours and it tells me I need to make a cast in my query, however every way I've tried keeps throwing me errors.

I know that if I do a query with a hardcoded status it works:

```
@Query("SELECT er FROM ExchangeRequest er WHERE er.status = 'PENDING'")
    fun findByStatus(status: ExchangeRequestStatus): Optional<List<ExchangeRequest>>
```

but otherwise I get this:

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: exchange_request_status = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

My question would be, where and how should I make the cast?

I also already have this in my entity for `exchange_request`:

```
@Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private var status: ExchangeRequestStatus,
```

and defined this outside the entity as well:

```
enum class ExchangeRequestStatus(val value: String) {
    PENDING("PENDING"), ACCEPTED("ACCEPTED"), REJECTED("REJECTED"), CANCELED("CANCELED")
}
```

In case it's necessary, here's my controller and my service:

```
@GetMapping("/status/{status}")
    fun getExchangeRequestByStatus(@PathVariable status: ExchangeRequestStatus): Optional<List<ExchangeRequestDTO>> {
        return exchangeRequestService.getByStatus(status)
    }
```

```
public fun getByStatus(status: ExchangeRequestStatus): Optional<List<ExchangeRequestDTO>> {
        val exchangeRequests =  exchangeRequestRepository.findByStatus(status)

        return exchangeRequests.map { requests ->
            requests.map { ExchangeRequestDTO(it) }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that enum can be automatically be converted only to original `VARCHAR`. By default Hibernate uses `ORDINAL` strategy mapping for enums. Your annotation `@Enumerated` is on the attribute, the repository knows nothing about it.

The first solution is to change `findByStatus`'s argument to String and add a cast to the query:

```
@Query("select er from ExchangeRequest er where sql('?::VARCHAR', er.status) = :status")
fun findAllByValue(status: String): List<MyTable>
```

The second one is a bit perverted, but maybe you enjoy it))

```
@Query("select er from ExchangeRequest er where sql('array_position(enum_range(?::EXCHANGE_REQUEST_STATUS), ?::EXCHANGE_REQUEST_STATUS)', er.status, er.status) = sql('(? + 1)', :status) ")
fun findAllByValue(status: ExchangeRequestStatus): List<MyTable>
```

Comment: I already tried changing the argument for string and when I make the call it tells me that the type is incorrect.

Comment: Oh sorry, the first solution also requires a small cast in the query, I forgot to add it initially. Now I added it to the the answer